# Facing issue in Document sharing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, appdelegate

I am on some document sharing issue. My iPhone has two applications. One app "SharingApp" shares a file from its bundle to another app "ViewerApp" using Document Interaction Controller. By default, the shared file will be saved to the document directory of "ViewerApp" under folder named "Inbox". I can get the url in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of "ViewerApp" as

```
NSURL *url = (NSURL*)[launchOptions valueForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
```

This scenario works perfectly if the "ViewerApp" is not been launched.

The problem I have is, incase, if the "ViewerApp" is in background state(or not killed) and if the file is shared from "SharingApp", `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called in `appDelegate` of "ViewerApp". So, I couldn't able to get the `url` as the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is not called(ViewerApp is already launched). "ViewerApp" just opens with the last shared `url` before entering to the background state.

How can I handle to get the `url` in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`? Please, share some ideas if you have come across this kind of issue. 
Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the following UIApplicationDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

This should solve your problem since this method will be called when your viewer app is in background

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue.  The problem is that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called when an application is already open but brought to the foreground.  I took my code out of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and instead put it inside handleOpenURL (also on the app delegate page)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {
        MainViewController *frontViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
        [frontViewController handleOpenURL:url]; //function on my main view controller class to do the necessary action

        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"Cannot Handle Opening This File."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        return NO;
    }
}
```